# Undefined reference to classes in subdirectories

Tags: c++, g++

I am having trouble getting a project of mine to compile. I have a directory structure as per below:

```
main/
 |--common/
 |    |-----lib/
 |    |      |----> help.o
 |    |---- help.cpp
 |    |---- help.h
 |    |---- makefile
 |--prog/
 |    |-----bin/
 |    |      |----> progMain
 |    |-----lib/
 |    |      |----> main.o
 |    |---- main.cpp
 |    |---- makefile
 |-- makefile
```

The main makefile compiles the code in common first then in prog. The compilation step works fine. The problem is I get the linker complaining `undefined reference to Help:: ...` main.cpp includes it with `#include "common/help.h"` The line in prog/makefile to build the executable is

```
g++ -o bin/progMain lib/main.o -L../common/lib/
```

I just cant get the linker to find the code in the Help class. I have tried

```
g++ -o bin/progMain lib/main.o ../common/lib/*.o
g++ -o bin/progMain lib/main.o -I../common/lib/
g++ -o bin/progMain lib/main.o -I../common/ -L../common/lib/
g++ -o bin/progMain lib/main.o -l../common/lib/help.o
```

But none of these help. Always the same undefined reference error.
Also note this is a simplified example and there are multiple classes in both `common/` and `prog/`

Comment: `g++ -o bin/progMain lib/main.o ../common/lib/help.o`

Comment: `-L../common/lib/` only tells the linker where it should search for libs. But this folder doesn't contain one, neither you link to it. You can either compile it separately and link to it with `g++ -o bin/progMain lib/main.o -L../common/lib/ -lhelp` or directly link the object file with `g++ -o bin/progMain lib/main.o ../common/lib/help.o`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply. @rustyx I found that works for the case where help.o is the only one in the directory but it I replace if with `../common/lib/*.o` it fails. @MateuszGrzejek I dont want to compile it into a .a or .so file unless I have to. Again in the real case there is more that one .o file in common/lib/

Comment: `*.o` is expanded by the shell, it won't work in a makefile. makefiles have other mechanisms to deal with that.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will do more reading up on wildcards in make.

Answer (score 0):

You should create object module library first:

```
ar -crs ../common/lib/libhelp.a ../common/lib/help.o
```

Then you should use this library for linking your executable:

```
g++ -o bin/progMain lib/main.o -L../common/lib/ -lhelp
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for your advise...